# Bodhi, shared folder appears in VM but not the subfolders

Tags: bodhi

[image: a]

You can see in the left folder `sf_Compiler` and in the top right how I configured in VirtualBox settings and bottom right the folders that I should be seeing in my VM which are present in the host.

Instructions are from here:  https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:StanfordOnline+SOE.YCSCS1+3T2020/7b74698308574f3c89d2ed498f26a019/

VM for the Stanford compiler course on Edx.

What else do I need to do to see all my host folders in the VM?

I tried clicking Insert Guest Additions CD from Device menu but it doesn't do anything.

I'm also unable to cd into that directory from terminal in the VM

```
compilers@compilers-vm:/media$ cd sf_Compiler
bash: cd: sf_Compiler: Permission denied
compilers@compilers-vm:/media$
```

I tried sudo cd as well.

Comment: switch to root and try navingating into the folder sf_Compiler

Comment: That worked @Alex.  `sudo su` got into root then I could cd there and see all my folders.  But why can't I see it without switching to root?

Comment: Probably cause of the permissions it was mounted with.